# Can ipywidgets access the notebook save/load functionality?

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In Jupiter lab, can I have an ipywidgets "Save" and "Load" buttons which call the save/load of the notebook?

And can I access the is_saved attribute of the notebook?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the ipywidget button with the module [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab). This module make a connection with the jupyterlab's backend/frontend.

```
from ipylab import JupyterFrontEnd
from ipywidgets import widgets

def save_button_func(button):
    app = JupyterFrontEnd()
    app.commands.execute('docmanager:save')

save_button = widgets.Button()
save_button.description = 'Save this notebook'
save_button.on_click(save_button_func)
save_button
```

to load notebook is the same logic, you can find the code with element inspect on the browser or search in git project.

Comment: Perfect. Much thanks. ipylab looks very powerful.